# How to create a javascript sentence (or paragraph) generator?

Tags: javascript, html, generator, paragraph, sentence

How can I build a javascript sentence (or paragraph) generator?

I've built a generator that generates one quote at a time when you click a button. The quote shows up inside a textarea inside 2 boxes.

But my problem is that it can only show one quote at a time.
I want to be able to *mix a bunch of half phrases together to make a paragraph*.

(ie.)

|The car  |is blue. | The car | is fast. |

and another result would be :

|The car | is green. | The car | is fast.|

- what is in between the "|"s are the different results.

P.s. I also want it all to be in one textarea and generated through a butten click. I have some coding done. I want to change it to make what a paragraph generator possible.

Original code :

CSS

```
<style>
div#box{
height : 330px;
width : 450px;
background-color : teal;
border : 1px solid black;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius : 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
margin : 0px auto;}

 div#box2{
 height : 300px;
 width : 430px;
 background-color : brown;
 border : 1px solid black;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius : 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 margin : 0px auto;
 margin-top: 15px;} 

div#boxTitle{
height : 60px;
width : 390px;
background-color : olive;
color : teal;
font-family : times new roman;
font-size : 15pt;
letter-spacing : 1px;
border : 1px solid black;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius : 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
text-decoration : bold;
text-transform : uppercase;
text-align : center;
margin : 0px auto;
margin-top : 13px;}


textarea{
height : 200px;
width : 390px;
background-color : olive;
color : black;
font-family : arial new, cursive, serif;
font-size : 11pt;
letter-spacing : 3px;
border : 1px solid black;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius : 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
text-decoration : italic;
text-align : center;
margin-left : 5%;
margin-right : 5%;
margin-top : 20px;} 

.button{
height : 40px;
width : 175px;
background-color : teal;
color : #bbb;
font-family : arial new;
font-size : 12pt;
border : 1px solid black;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius : 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius:     10px;
text-decoration : bold;
text-align : center;
margin-left: 50%;}
</style>
```

Javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 var Quotes = new Array(); 

 Quotes[0]="your first quote.";
 Quotes[1]="your second quote. "; 
 Quotes[2]="your third quote.  "; 


function getQuote(){ var seed      = Math.floor(Math.random() * 
Quotes.length); return     Quotes[seed]; } 

 </script>
```

HTML

```
  <div id="box">
 <div id="box2">
 <div      id="boxTitle"><br>generator      title</div>
 <textarea id="quoteBody"></textarea>
 </div></div>

  <br><br>
  <input type="button"    class="button" value="Get a   new quote"    onclick="document.   getElementById('quoteBody').  innerHTML = getQuote();" />
```

Comment: Modify the function so you pass it the array to get a phrase from. Call it once for each array, concatenate the results.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var nouns = ["car","horse","apple","person","chimp"];
 var adjectives = ["red","fast","lonely","hungry","insane"];

function getQuote(){ 
var randomNounIndex      = Math.floor(Math.random() * nouns.length);
var randomAdjectiveIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * adjectives.length);
var retVal="The "+nouns[randomNounIndex]+" is "+adjectives[randomAdjectiveIndex]+".";
return retVal;
} 
</script>
```

Once you get the idea you can modify that to return all manner of complicated sentances containing more words, parts of speech, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something generic like:

```
// Return a random element of an array
function getRandomElement(arr) {
  return arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0];
}

// Return a string of elements chosen randomly from a sequence of arrays
function genPhrase() {
  var phrases = [
     ['Huge','Extraordinary','Average','Amazing'],
     ['Intelligence','Ignorance','Mediocraty','Courage', 'Cowardice']
  ];
  var phrase = [];
  phrases.forEach(function(a) {phrase.push(getRandomElement(a));});
  return phrase.join(' ');
}

// Just for play..   
for (var i=5; i; i--) {
  document.write(genPhrase() + '<br>');
}
```

Note that *forEach* requires ES5 support. Trivial to replace with a for loop if required.